# Doing calculations while creating a List (in Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm getting data from an API and storing it on Python dictionary (and then a list of dictionaries).

I need to do calculations (max, sum, divisions...) on the dictionary data to create extra data to add to the same dictionary/list.

My current code looks like this:

```
stream = whatever (whatever, whatever)
keywords = []

for batch in stream:
    for row in batch.results:

        max_clicks = max(data_keywords["keywords_clicks"])
        weighted_clicks = sum(data_keywords["keywords_weighted"])/sum(data_keywords["keywords_clicks"])

        data_keywords = {}
        data_keywords["keywords_text"] = row.ad_group_criterion.keyword.text
        data_keywords["keywords_clicks"] = row.metrics.clicks  
        data_keywords["keywords_conversion_rate"] = row.metrics.conversions_from_interactions_rate
        data_keywords["keywords_weighted"] = row.metrics.clicks * row.metrics.conversions_from_interactions_rate  
        data_keywords["etv"] = (data_keywords["keywords_clicks"]/max_clicks*data_keywords["keywords_conversion_rate"])+((1-data_keywords["keywords_clicks"]/max_clicks)*weighted_clicks)
        keywords.append(data_keywords)
```

This doesn't work, it gives UnboundLocalError (local variable 'data_keywords' referenced before assignment). I've tried different options and got different errors.

data_keywords["etv"] is what I want to calculate ("max_clicks", "weighted_clicks" and data_keywords["keywords_weighted"] are intermediate calculations for that)

The main problem is that I need to calculate max and sum for all values inside the dictionary, then do a calculation using that max and sum for each value and then store the results in the dictionary itself.

So I don't know where to put the code to do the calculations (before the dictionary, inside the dictionary, after the dictionary or a mix)

I guess it should be possible, but I'm a Python/programming newbie and can't figure this out.

It's probably not relevant, but in case you are wondering, I'm trying to create a weighted sort (https://moz.com/blog/build-your-own-weighted-sort). And I can't use models/database to store data.

Thanks!

EDIT: Some extra info, in case it helps understand better what I need: The results that the `keywords` list gives without the calculations is something like this:

```
[{'keywords_text': 'whatever', 'keywords_clicks': 5, 'keywords_conversion_rate': 6.3}, {'keywords_text': 'whatever2', 'keywords_clicks': 50, 'keywords_conversion_rate': 2.3}, {'keywords_text': 'whatever3', 'keywords_clicks': 20, 'keywords_conversion_rate': 2.0}]
```

I want basically to add to this keywords list a new key/value of `'etv': 8.5` or whatever for each keyword. That `etv` should come from the formula that I put on my code (data_keywords["etv"] = ...) but maybe it needs changes to work in Python.

The info from this "original" keywords list comes directly from the API (I don't have that data stored anywhere) and it works perfectly if I just request the info and store it in that list. But when the problems come when I introduce the calculations (specially using sum and max inside a loop I guess).

Comment: You are trying to use the variable `data_keywords` before defining it.

Comment: How can you get the max and sum of values in a dictionary when you haven't created the dictionary yet?

Answer (score -1):

The UnboundLocalError is because you are trying to access data_keywords["keywords_clicks"] before you have declared data_keywords or set the value for "keywords_clicks".

Also, I think you need to be clearer about what data structure you are trying to create.  You mention "a list of dictionaries" which I don't see.  Maybe you are trying to create a dictionary of lists, but it looks like you overwrite the dictionary values each time you go through your loop.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking why I get that error (I know that), I'm asking how to do what I want to do. Regarding the data structure/naming: "keywords" is a list and and "data_keywords" is a dictionary. I call that a list of dictionaries, but maybe it's not the correct name. Anyway, that data structure works perfectly when I don't need to do calculations "inside" (it adds new dictionaries inside the list as it's supposed to, no overwriting at all). I'm only asking how to do those calculations.

Answer (score -1):

*adding my response as an answer, as I do not have enough reputation to comment*

To get rid of assignment error just move the line `data_keywords = {}` above `max_clicks = max(data_keywords["keywords_clicks"])`

Here you are trying to access a local variable before its declaration. The code in this case is trying to access a global variable which doesn't seems to exist.

```
stream = whatever (whatever, whatever) 
keywords = []

for batch in stream:
 for row in batch.results:    
    data_keywords = {}
    max_clicks = max(data_keywords["keywords_clicks"])
    weighted_clicks = sum(data_keywords["keywords_weighted"])/sum(data_keywords["keywords_clicks"])

    data_keywords["keywords_text"] = row.ad_group_criterion.keyword.text
    data_keywords["keywords_clicks"] = row.metrics.clicks  
    data_keywords["keywords_conversion_rate"] = row.metrics.conversions_from_interactions_rate
    data_keywords["keywords_weighted"] = row.metrics.clicks * row.metrics.conversions_from_interactions_rate  
    data_keywords["etv"] = (data_keywords["keywords_clicks"]/max_clicks*data_keywords["keywords_conversion_rate"])+((1-data_keywords["keywords_clicks"]/max_clicks)*weighted_clicks)
    keywords.append(data_keywords)
```

More on that [here](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment/)

Comment: It doesn't work. Now it gives a different error: KeyError at /whatever 'keywords_clicks'. I've tried several of those combinations/orders without any luck. I guess the main problem is that I need to do calculations inside the loop and add the results to the dictionary, but some of those calculations can't be done while still looping (to do a max() and sum() you need to have the totals)

Comment: Well, I was trying to explain reason for `UnboundLocalError`. If you already aware of that, just update your question to actual error and a sample input if possible. Python `sum` and `max` are valid functions. How can you expect us to know the actual error?

Comment: From your comment above  re:`It gives me TypeError at /whatever 'int' object is not iterable` value of `data_keywords["keywords_clicks"]` doesn't seems to be a list. Try printing the value and or typeof of `data_keywords["keywords_clicks"]` before using higher order funtions

Comment: I don't want you to know the error/s, I want to know possible solutions for what I want to achieve. "data_keywords" is a dictionary. "keywords" is a list (with the data from different instances of "data_keywords" appended inside). I thought that was clear from my code, but maybe it's not.  This data structure works perfectly without the calculations (sum, max, etc.). But I don't know how and where to introduce the calculations so data_keywords["etv"] (the final calculation) works OK.

Answer (score -1):

You can't refer to elements of the dictionary before you create it. Move those variable assignments down to after you assign the dictionary elements.

```
for batch in stream:
    for row in batch.results:
        data_keywords = {}
        data_keywords["keywords_text"] = row.ad_group_criterion.keyword.text
        data_keywords["keywords_clicks"] = row.metrics.clicks  
        data_keywords["keywords_conversion_rate"] = row.metrics.conversions_from_interactions_rate
        data_keywords["keywords_weighted"] = row.metrics.clicks * row.metrics.conversions_from_interactions_rate  

        max_clicks = max(data_keywords["keywords_clicks"])
        weighted_clicks = sum(data_keywords["keywords_weighted"])/sum(data_keywords["keywords_clicks"])

        data_keywords["etv"] = (data_keywords["keywords_clicks"]/max_clicks*data_keywords["keywords_conversion_rate"])+((1-data_keywords["keywords_clicks"]/max_clicks)*weighted_clicks)
        keywords.append(data_keywords)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that too and it doesn't work. It gives me TypeError at /whatever 'int' object is not iterable. I think it's not just about changing the order. I guess the main problem is that I need to do calculations inside the loop and add the results to the dictionary, but some of those calculations can't be done while still looping (to do a max() and sum() you need to have the totals)

Comment: If it's not a list, what do you mean by trying to get the maximum and sum?

Comment: I suspect you want to get the maximum and sum of something across all rows in the batch, not a single row.

Comment: You need to update the question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: It is a list (you can see it on the first part, that you removed in your code). I think my desired results have been explained already. You can see the max and sum that I need in my code. I basically want the data_keywords["etv"] calculation to work OK and add the results of that calculation to the list.

Comment: Where can I see that `row.metrics.clicks` is a list?

Comment: The only list I can see in your code is `keywords`.

Comment: I've never said that row.metrics.clicks is a list (I don't even know what is the name for that, I'm a Python beginner as I've said). Keywords is a list, yes. The data from data_keywords (different instances/keywords) is appended/added to the keywords list. Anyway, I will try to add more info to my original question.

Comment: You did `data_keywords["keywords_clicks"] = row.metrics.clicks`. So `max(data_keywords["keywords_clicks"])` is the same as `max(row.metrics.clicks)`. And that requires it to be a list that you can get the maximum of.

Comment: I think what you may want is `max(x['keyword_clicks'] for x in keywords)`

Comment: But what should this be on the first iteration, before anything has been added to `keywords`?

Comment: I've added extra info to my original question, maybe that helps understand what I want to achieve. Sorry, but I'm a Python newbie and using basically code examples copied from the API docs, I don't fully understand what you explain and ask. If you think `max(x['keyword_clicks'] for x in keywords)` could be the answer, please explain where I should put it exactly. But please be aware that max is just one step of the calculations, the end calculation that I want is the formula on data_keywords["etv"] . Thanks!